# Make a User Account same as it is in Safe Mode

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, safe-mode

I have Windows 7 in my laptop which has Single User Account. I noticed that in Safe Mode laptop is much faster than usual.

So I want to create a User Account which has all properties same as when laptops runs in Safe Mode. So that I can use this account for Internet Access only.

My question is how can I make such an account which behaves like it is in Safe Mode?

Comment: In Safe Mode, most services and features are unavailable. That’s what makes it fast—and useless for actual work. It’s not about user accounts.

Comment: @DanielB I tried by making a new account with Parental Control by blocking lots of services, but when I logged into that account a no. of pop ups open asking service blocked by Parental Control.

Comment: Like I said: This is not about user accounts. It’s about the basic mode of operation of Windows. It is *fundamentally different* in Safe Mode. You cannot replicate this behavior.

Comment: If you want to ask another question, you are free to do so. By asking another question, not editing this one.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> This is not about user accounts. It’s about the basic mode of operation of Windows. It is fundamentally different in Safe Mode. You cannot replicate this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it exactly like safe mode, but you can disable a some services to help a little with the speed.  The trick is to know which ones you don't need, and that's not something that we can recommend blindly.  Some services should never be disabled, while others may be acceptable in your situation.  For example, the Indexing service may not be needed, and will free up your hard drive at the expense of slower file searches.

I would look elsewhere first to improve system performance.  A RAM upgrade can be one of the simplest cheapest upgrades if your computer is fairly low on it.